# How to remove duplicated rows from table with arrays in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

there is a table in BigQuery that has REPEATED type columns and has duplicated rows, since the table has arrays I cannot use distinct to grab only one row.

Table looks something like this:

[image: image1]

I want to remove the duplicated rows, the output should be like this:

[image: image2]

I didn't find a way to come up with the above result, anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *
from your_table t
where true
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by format('%t', t))
```

Answer (score 0):

add 1 columnXYZ with autogenerated number or create numbering in this column by yourself. 1 unique number per each row.

then make query with grouping to your data and "select max(columnXYZ) as RowsToDelete" for each group, this will select only last duplicates in your data. then make deletion by these RowsToDelete.

Answer (score 0):

I use sample data. This case the id number 1 was duplicated. You can use this query.

```
 WITH data AS (
  SELECT 1 id, ["a", "a", "b"] strings,5 strings2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 id, ["a", "a", "b"] strings,5 strings2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 id, ["z", "a", "b"] strings,3 strings2
)


SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT string) strings, strings2
FROM data, UNNEST(strings) string
GROUP BY id,strings2
```

This was my result.

[image]